# Delete row from uitableview crashes

Tags: iphone, uitableview, crash, row

I simply try to delete a row from a `UITableView` with the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
     {
         [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
     }
}
```

The problem is that my app crashes. (GDB: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION".)
Anybody know why?

Comment: Do you have a symbolic breakpoint on objc_exception_throw? If not, try adding that and seeing where execution stops.

Comment: also, if you put 4 spaces in front of your code it will be better formatted and easier to read.

Comment: ok, thanks for formatting my code. the execution stops here:  +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] ... any idea?

Comment: Is there error description in console?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably need to change the number returned in

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

for the `indexPath.section` to be one lower than before the deletion.

Comment: yep, I had to remove the object out of my array first before deleting this row. know it works! thanks